# Can one still download 10.04 netbook edition

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-netbook

I would like to get the iso image of Ubuntu 10.04 netbook edition but can't find it on the Ubuntu web site.

Is this file still available? If so, could someone point me to a link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get images for netbooks with ARM processors: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ports/releases/lucid/.

However, please be warned that there is no support for discontinued releases and any questions opened here will be closed as off-topic. You may be able to get assistance on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), though.

There is no intel .iso there. For that you need to use one of the isos mentioned here:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/183716/1992
- https://askubuntu.com/a/183605/1992

Comment: Downvoted because _green7_'s answer is correct and official...

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun fixed.

Comment: - and flipped my vote up instead :)

Answer (score 4):

For the netbook edition of Ubuntu 10.04, go to this link: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ports/releases/lucid/.

NB: These are for the ARM architecture, not for intel PCs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can find the iso here. http://kambing.ui.ac.id/iso/ubuntu/releases/lucid/

Comment: This link has the i386 iso.

Answer (score 1):

Also:
http://mirror.linux.org.au/ubuntu-releases/10.04/ubuntu-10.04-netbook-i386.iso
http://linuxfreedom.com/ubuntu-releases/10.04.1/ubuntu-10.04-netbook-i386.iso
http://mirror.exetel.com.au/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu-releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04-netbook-i386.iso

the md5sum should be:
712277c7868ab374c4d3c73cff1d95cb ubuntu-10.04-netbook-i386.iso
(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes#A10.04_LTS)

Comment: ubuntu.{com|org|...} no longer has any ubuntu-10.04-netbook-i386.iso download sources (ie. there is NO http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ports/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04-netbook-i386.iso link
) - only references, like checksums, to the same